# How to avoid duplicate with routes.MapRoute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

This is my route in my RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "ComputerSearch",
  url: "eq",
  defaults: new { controller = "Computer", action = "Search", ID = UrlParameter.Optional },
  namespaces: new[] { "Pixel.Inforworld.Website.Controllers" }
);
```

So far it is working well with URL like this

```
https://mywebsite.com/eq?cat=intel
```

However, this URL is also existing

```
https://mywebsite.com/Computer/Search?cat=intel
```

Both of the URLs above give the same contents, actually the same page and Google Search Console flagged my site as

```
Page is not indexed: Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user
```

This is my preferred URL

```
https://mywebsite.com/eq?cat=intel
```

So the question, is how do I disable or make /Computer/Search/ go away?

Answer (score 0):

and thanks to ChatGPT, it solved it for me

To make the URL "/Computer/Search" go away and only have the preferred URL "/eq" accessible, you can remove or comment out the corresponding route mapping in your RouteConfig.cs file.

Here's how you can modify the code in your RouteConfig.cs file to achieve this:

```cs
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "ComputerSearch",
  url: "eq",
  defaults: new { controller = "Computer", action = "Search", ID = UrlParameter.Optional },
  namespaces: new[] { "Pixel.Inforworld.Website.Controllers" }
);

// Comment out or remove the following route mapping
// routes.MapRoute(
//   name: "Default",
//   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
//   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
//   namespaces: new[] { "Pixel.Inforworld.Website.Controllers" }
// );
```

By commenting out or removing the default route mapping, which is the one responsible for handling the URL "/Computer/Search", you ensure that it is no longer accessible. Only the route mapping for "/eq" will be active, and that will be the preferred URL for your desired page.

After making these changes, make sure to test your application thoroughly to ensure that everything functions as expected and that there are no unintended side effects.